# How to search in polynomial hash table in ascending order in C?

Tags: algorithm, hash, hashtable

I there guys,

i'm developing a small program in C, that reads strings from a .txt file with 2 letters and 3 numbers format. Like this

```
AB123
```

I developed a polynomial hash function, that calculates an hash key like this

```
hash key(k) = k1 + k2*A² + k3*A^3... +Kn*A^n
```

where k1 is the 1º letter of the word, k2 the 2º (...) and A is a prime number to improve the number of collisions, in my case its 11.

Ok, so i got the table generated, i can search in the table no problem, but only if i got the full word... That i could figure it out.

But what if i only want to use the first letter? Is it possible to search in the hash table, and get the elements started by for example 'A' without going through every element?

Answer (score 0):

In order to have more functionality you have to introduce more data structures. It all depends on how deep you want to go, which depends on what exactly you need to code to do.

I suspect that you want some kind of filtering for the user. When user enters "A" it should be given all strings that have "A" at the start, and when afterwards it enters "B" the list should be filtered down to all strings starting with "AB".

If this is the case then you don't need over-complicated structures. Just iterate through the list and give the user the appropriate sublist. Humans are slow, and they won't notice the difference between 3 ms response and 300 ms response.

Comment: I need to code just simple queries to the hash table. This strings i gave an example, are for example products. I want to query the table, to give me all products that start with the letter 'A' for example. With a full word i don't have any problems, it's just generate the hash for it... But only the first character... How would more structures help?

Comment: @PedroLino There are only 676000 possible combinations of the form AANNN, and I guess that there are even less items in the table. Why not just iterate through the whole table? Is that acceptable? Why not?

Comment: It's a project to the university. We are 4 guys developing this, and it's kind of a supermarket. This code is for clients. We have them for products too, and they have another number on the word. Then we have to link products with clients if they buy it. We are developing AVL tree, hash tables, and a variation with graphs. I'm with the hash. So doing a table won't cut it. I may consider doing a table that tells me where the leter starts... for example, 'A' goes from 0 to 100, B would go from 101 to X. And apply the hash to those values. It would have a lot of colitions i guess

Answer (score 0):

If your hash function is well designed, every place in the table is capable of storing a string beginning with any prefix, so this approach is doomed from the start.

It sounds like what you really want might be a [trie](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie).

Comment: Not what i want. I really want to make this as an hash table. I can change the algorithm to generate the hash, or change structures... But i want to do a hash not a tree :) But this trie, isn't good for this problem either. AVL would be best for it :)

Comment: Trie is asymptotically better: it takes advantage of the radix nature of your data rather than being comparison based. Who knows how that will translate into practice with whatever data you're working with. I really don't think hash tables are the right structure for whatever application you're doing this for, although I can't know for sure since you haven't said what it is.. Research into weird hash tables is fun, although my first impression is that whatever you do to make it work will end up secretly being an odd implementation of a trie.

Comment: I'm assuming you want to be able to search on arbitrary prefixes; if you really just want the first letter, an easy solution is to have one hash table for each initial letter.

Comment: That's one idea i am considering. :) Count all the A words, and generate them in that range.